Complement of set with positive, but non-full, Lebesgue measure contains interval?
Denote the Lebesgue measure restricted to the interval $[0,1]$ by $\lambda$.
Suppose $A$ is and measurable and $0 < \lambda(A) < 1$. Suppose additionally that $A$ contains no intervals.
Is it true that $A^c$ must contain a non-empty interval (does not matter of which kind)? If not, what's a good counter-example? I suspect this isn't true but cannot construct my own counter-example.

Take $A=(\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1/2])\cup ([1/2,1]\backslash\mathbb{Q})$, which is measurable with $\lambda(A)=1/2$ and does not contain any intervals.
Then, $A^c=([0,1/2]\backslash\mathbb{Q})\cup (\mathbb{Q}\cap [1/2,1])$, which does not contain any interval as the rationals are dense in $[0,1/2]$ and the irrationals are dense in $[1/2,1]$.

Thanks. That works. I forgot to add an additional requirement on $A$ stipulating that it does not contain any intervals. I have edited my question accordingly.

@diffrep Edited my response; removing the rationals from $[1/2,1]$ is enough.

If I strengthen the assumptions and assume $A$ to be compact. Does this still work?

If $A$ is compact, then it is closed so its complementary is an open set and must contain an interval.

Following the edit and previous comments,
Any compact set in a Hausdorff space is necessarily closed. So if $A \subseteq [0, 1]$ is compact then $[0,1] \setminus A$ must be open and hence contains a non-trivial interval, unless $[0,1]\setminus A$ is empty.
